# making Net-beans available to different users on Ubuntu Machine who are accessing through remote Desktop

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have installed Net-beans on a Ubuntu Machine. The Net-beans is used to connect to database and other resources in the Ubuntu machine. It's working fine.

2-3 users have to work on the code base in the Ubuntu machine just mentioned, So I have to create 2-3 different users in the Ubuntu machine. Each of these users access the machine using remote desktop access.

How do I make different instances of Net-beans available to different users so that they can access the different instances simultaneous?

Comment: `2-3 users have to work on the code base in the Ubuntu machine` - this is bizarre unless your remote terminals are dumb terminals. Why can't you simply use version control with the remote terminals checking out the codebase in their own Netbeans workspaces?

Answer (score 1):

You need SVN: check out this link http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html .

If you need to access simultaneously to the same project, this is by far the best choice. However you will need to have NetBeans installed on the developers' PCs